# Angular: not-to-update values in ngx-datatable-column if modal (popup) aborted

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have a ngx-datatable with several columns like this:

```
  <ngx-datatable-column name="PLZ/Ort" prop="plzCity" [flexGrow]="1" >
    <ng-template let-column="column" let-sort="sortFn" let-sortDir="sortDir" ngx-datatable-header-template>
      <span (click)="sort($event, sortDir, sortFn)">PLZ/Ort</span>
    </ng-template>
   </ngx-datatable-column>
```

If I click on the line a modal (popup) appears with pre-filled values from the row of this datatable. If I change anything and save the modal disappears and the new values appear in the row. (Intended)

If I change the values in the modal and click on 'abort' the modal also disappears and the new values also appear in the row. (Unintended). To get back the original values I need to reload the page again. (Doable, but painful)

So I tried to implement a workaround: in `ngOnInit()` I made a deep copy of the JSON Object which contains the values both of the `ngx-datatable` and the modal. Let's call this object gaa. Since it happens prior to any user interaction it contains the original values.

In `abort()` function I just reassign the original values to gaa object.

```
` abort() {
    console.log('close');
    console.log(this.changes)
    this.gaa = this.oldGaa; //it is proven that oldGaa contains the unchanged values.
    this.activeModal.close();
  }`
```

It does not work however. The cloned object contains the right (unchanged) values, but row's value in the datatable will still be updated with the changed values. (Strangely, I can get the right values displayed if I stop the whole thing with the debugger for a short time. But without the debugger- no chance. The values get updated despite the assigment. )

Maybe the whole approach is wrong. How can I not-to-update the values of the row if the user click on 'Abort'?

Comment: Hi, just to check, is `gaa` the object that is supplied to the `[rows]` input binding? Meaning it is something like this?  `<ngx-datatable [rows]="gaa" .....>` I might know the reason why it isnt working

Comment: yes. 'Gaa' is JSON object bound to both the rows in the Datatable and also to the fields of the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a 'deep copy' of `gaa`, I would recommend you to create a [shallow copy](https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c) of it, such that the memory address/reference is copied. This is because ngx-datatable is [built with onPush change detection](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/change-detection), thus this will allow Angular's change detection to be triggered accordingly.

We use ES6's spread syntax to craete a shallow copy of `gaa`.

```
this.temp = [...this.gaa];
```

Now, when you abort your abort changes, we reassign `gaa` with the previously created shallow clone, `temp`.

```
abort() {
  this.gaa = this.temp;
  this.activeModal.close();
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work unfortunately. Maybe I have mistaken something but the shallow copy 'temp' doesn't even contain the original values. So in case the assignemnt in 'abort' is not necessary since this.gaa and this.temp refer to the same object thus they  and all of their fields are identical.

Comment: @Sanyifejű I guess that is because on that modal, when you make any changes, the references points to `temp`? I guess that same theory applies to your initial code for `gaa`/`oldgaa` as well?